# Does sizing down and increasing resolution for printing affect sharpness?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design

I have a photo that is at 120x60 cm at 72ppi. If I resize it to 50x23 cm at 300ppi for a print job where the image will be scaled down further will it affect the sharpness of the image?

Comment: You realise that's upscaling, not downscaling?

Comment: You're enlarging the image by 441%. It will affect sharpness.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the question as asked is "yes" it will be less sharp as bicubic interpolation (resampling) can be thought of as an averaging method.

But as @tetsujin alluded to in the comment, lowering the print size while increasing the pixels per inch can actually upsample the image.

I am going to use inches, since we are using ppi, which implicitly is in inches.

A 10 inch image at 72ppi is 720 pixels. If I place a copy of this in indesign without resampling, set to  5 inches, **it is still 720pixels, but it is now 144ppi**. PPI is always a derived number: pixels divided by inches (the literal definition of pixels per inch).

Back to your example, you have roughly 120cm * 2.9 (convert 72 ppi to p/mm, which is about 2.88). That is 3480px. **If you resample, it so that it is half the size, but 300ppi (about 11.8 p/mm), you get 7080px.** My conversions may be a little off, but I hope the concept is clear.

I believe that compositing programs like inDesign have an implicit 300ppi assumption when there isn't anything specified, but you can have essentially arbitrary resolution (ppi) for your images and they will not be resampled unless the particular output method specifies it. You can disable all downsampling when exporting PDF for example. The effective resolution can be seen on the links palette when looking at the details of any individual linked asset.

In any event the rule of thumb has always been to try and avoid scaling up more than 2x or scaling down less than about 50%. You can get away with a lot more, but in those cases you need to examine your output carefully.

I once placed a 250px jpg thumbnail as a full-page bleed for position and forgot to swap out the high res photo after design approval, It printed fine and I only noticed because I had to do a revision 2 years later.

Answer (score 1):

Some numbers.

cm > in > @72 ppi

```
120 > 47.24 > 3401 
 60 > 23.62 > 1700
```

Original image 3401 x 1700 px.

cm > in > @300 ppi

```
50 > 19.68 > 5905
23 > 09.05 > 2716
```

Target image 5905 x 2716 px (Notice that you need to crop the image)

**The image will not be scaled down, will be upscaled.**

So, let's analyze first your image without any transformation.

You want an image of half the physical size. If you do not touch it it will be simply double. 144 PPI.

To maximize sharpness, I would double the size of the image 8with bicubic sharper on Photoshop, or with any bicubic method and apply some sharpening on other programs). This would be 288ppi and leave it there.